# Why does gnome-terminal swallow some of my Alt tmux shortcuts?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, tmux

I've enabled a bunch of no-prefix shortcuts in tmux (like <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> for new window, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd> for next), which has made my life so much better. The problem was, my shortcuts didn't always work. Maybe every 5-10 presses, something would just swallow the keypress, and I'd have to do it again. Sometimes it would send input to the terminal, which was even worse.

I worked this out for myself, but I wanted to post it as a question because I couldn't find anything when I was searching. Lots of people talk about the ["menu access key" problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30224/how-to-disable-the-alt-hotkey-behavior-on-gnome-terminal), but this is actually unrelated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turned out to be Unity. The bare <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is the default *Key to show the HUD*, and somehow that binding was occasionally mucking with <kbd>Alt</kbd> chords in my terminal. Here's how to unset it:

Install ccsm if you don't have it

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open the program

```
ccsm
```

In the window that comes up, find the **Unity** plugin under the **Desktop** section. The very first item in there is **Key to show the HUD**, which defaults to `<Alt>`. Click on the `<Alt>` button and uncheck the *Enabled* box. Done!