# How to disable the Alt+E keyboard shortcut?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'm aware from [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1113420) forum post that there is a bug associated with the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> key sequence. It's a very ergonomic bind that could be used for many things.

Is there any way around this annoying little bug?

Comment: Posts on this bug report link to [How to disable the alt-hotkey behavior on gnome terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30224/how-to-disable-the-alt-hotkey-behavior-on-gnome-terminal), [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124815/how-do-i-enable-emacs-keybindings-in-apps-such-as-google-chrome#comment332725_233539) and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1735533, do these help (and if not, why not)? What did you try, what results/problems did you experience? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: To close-voters: This is not a bug report, but rather asks for possible workarounds around an existing bug. IMO that's not [ÖT](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41654339#41654339).

Comment: I asked it again because there hasn't been an answer yet.

Comment: The  AU question has five answers – what do you mean?

Comment: Check again. There is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the most useful program in my entire life.

It's called AutoKey,

To install `sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk`

Learn it; it's quite simple.

Then hack away at getting around annoying key bugs or limitations.


For example in this case:

Just bind <kbd>Alt+E</kbd> to a sequence you will never use like: <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Alt+f12</kbd>