# Disable HUD in Skype on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, hud

I'm having `skypeforlinux` and whenever I click `alt`, it redirects the pointer to the top bar menu which I found absolutely annoying. I use `alt + shift` to switch between input layouts.

I have installed `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` but found `Ubuntu Unity Plugin` missing in `Desktop`. I also couldn't find `Key to show the HUD` on Ubuntu 20.04. How can I disable HUD globally?

Comment: Are you using Unity in Ubuntu 20.04? [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1298124/edit) your question to add this information.

Comment: Hi @Archisman Panigrahi, sorry for the late reply, I'm using the default one on Ubuntu 20.04, GNOME I suppose.

Comment: HUD was a Unity feature and it is missing in GNOME. I don't know how you have enabled HUD in GNOME

Comment: Not sure holding Alt to navigate on the top bar menu categorised as HUD. Thís question might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/30224/how-to-disable-the-alt-hotkey-behavior-on-gnome-terminal. None of the answers actually solves my problem, however.

Comment: @TriNguyen Have you solve it?

Comment: This answer helped me. https://askubuntu.com/a/1260256/520674

Comment: Hi @Nick, my problem wasn't how to update change layout shortcut to alt + shift, I have got it working already. The problem was, whenever I switch the layout, the pointer went to the menu bar instead of keeps staying at the text box. This appears on certain applications such as Skype in my case. Chrome works flawlessly however.

Comment: As I see answer above helped me but not completely. If I press Shift+Alt - layout changes and pointer not went to menu, all is well. But if I press Alt+Shift - pointer still went to menu. 2021 behind window, but problem in Electron applications still occurs...

Comment: Hi @Nick, yes the order does matter. Thank you anyway.